# Deducing template parameter types for each type in parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, c++17, template-argument-deduction

Let's say I have a type

```
template <class T, class U>
class Pass
{
};
```

I want to make a class that will accept a list of `Pass` objects, each with arbitrary `T` and `U` and make 3 `std::tuple`s.

Something like this:

```
template<template <typename P1, typename P2> class... T>
    class Test
    {
    public:
        Test(T<P1, P2>... passes) {}

        std::tuple<T<P1, P2>...> tuple1;
        std::tuple<P1...> tuple2;
        std::tuple<P2...> tuple3;
    };
```

And then create an instance:

```
Test t{ Pass<int, float>(), Pass<int, int>(), Pass<std::string, float>() };
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes:

```
template <typename... >
struct Test;

template <typename... T, typename... U>
struct Test<Pass<T, U>...>
{
    Test(Pass<T, U>...);

    std::tuple<Pass<T, U>...> tuple1;
    std::tuple<T...> tuple2;
    std::tuple<U...> tuple3;
};

template <typename... T, typename... U>
Test(Pass<T, U>...) -> Test<Pass<T, U>...>;
```

We need the deduction guide here because class template argument deduction only implicitly considers the primary template's constructors and the primary in this case has no constructors.

---

Note that this declaration:

```
template <template <typename P1, typename P2> class... T>
struct X { };
```

Means the same thing as this declaration:

```
template <template <typename, typename> class... T>
struct X { };
```

Which means a parameter pack of binary class templates - not specific types. Such a class template might be instantiated with:

```
X<Pass, std::pair, std::vector> x;
```

Comment: Deduction guides are new to me, I'll have to digest your answer for some time

Comment: Didn't you mean template
 <typename... >
struct Pass (instead of Test);

Comment: @PavloMuratov I don't know what the second question is referring to.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why do we need 
template <typename... >
struct Test;

Comment: @PavloMuratov That's the primary template. We declare a specialization that only accepts specializations of `Pass`, to deduce the underlying packs `T` and `U`.

Comment: @PavloMuratov Deduction guides are more or less a replacement for `makeX` template functions that existed only for deducing template arguments. You can write this code without deduction guides (or C++17) by requiring that `Test` is always created via a `makeTest` function template (which deduces the template parameters of the `Test` objects it is passed and explicitly specifies them for the `Test` it creates).

Comment: @PavloMuratov The core of this answer is that you need type deduction to go from `Pass<T1, T2>...` to the two lists `T1...`, `T2...` (which is all you want). Functions (either through the overload set formed by CTAD/constructors or by using a simple `makeTest` function template) provide this deduction context. You cannot specify that the template arguments of `Test` should be `Pass`es in a primary template signature, you need a specialization for this. The rest is explained in the answer.

Comment: @Barry how can I derive this code myself, which part of the standard should I read?

Comment: @PavloMuratov The standard is not a tutorial. It's not where you go to learn how to write code. Nico Josuttis has a new C++17 book, you could check that out. Otherwise in this case google for class template argument deduction, you should find several descriptions of it.